# Laravel 5 - Eloquent Query - Is this possible?

Tags: sql, laravel-5

I want to find all of the "Posts" that have users. Users are assigned in groups and I want to find all of the "Posts" that have a particular user group. I can get the posts by name, and that have a usergroup:

```
$results = Post::PostBySlug("Testing")
                    ->with('groups', 'groups.users')
                    ->first();
```

This works, but, returns all of the user groups that are assigned to a particular group. I want to do it so that I can select the post, by the slug, and return all the users of a particular group. I have tried:

```
$results = Post::PostBySlug("Testing")
           ->with('groups', 'groups.users')
           ->where('groups.id', '=', 1);
```

But this did not return anything, only an unknown column. I have tried to do:

```
$results = Post::PostBySlug("Testing")
               ->with('groups AS testing', 'groups.users')
               ->where('testing.id', '=', 1);
```

But yet, no further. Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong, or suggest an alternative approach to this?

Comment: Have you seen the query generated in DebugBar? That can help you to understand why the query is not working. https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Comment: Hi, You can use `->with(['groups' => function($query)
{
    $query->where('id', '=', 1);

}])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a query scope with the given group id.

```php
class Post extends Model {
    public function scopeInGroup($query, $group_id) {
        return $query->whereHas('groups', function($query) use ($group_id) {
            return $query->where('id', $group_id);
        }
    }
}
```

Then your query would be:

```php
Post::PostBySlug('Testing')
    ->InGroup(1)
    ->with('groups.users')
    ->get();
```